# A bug about the template and iterator

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T>
class iVector
{
protected:
    int _size;
    T * _vector;

public:
    typedef T * iterator;//My definition of iterator
    iVector(int n);
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

};
//constructor:
template<class T>
iVector<T>::iVector(int n) : _size(n)
{

}
template<class T>
iterator iVector<T>::begin()
{

}
template<class T>
iterator iVector<T>::end()
{

}
```

I don't know why VS2017 tells me that the "iterator" is not defined. And Dev-
C++ tells me that "iterator" does not name a type. The question happens on :

```
iterator iVector<T>::begin();
iterator iVector<T>::end();
```

But I think I have defined it on :

```
typedef T * iterator;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to qualify the name with the class name when use it out of the class definition. e.g.

```
template<class T>
typename iVector<T>::iterator iVector<T>::begin()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! I have understood!

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to *"verbose"*

```
template<class T>
typename iVector<T>::iterator
iVector<T>::begin()
{
    // ...
}
```

you may use

```
template<class T>
auto iVector<T>::bagin()
-> iterator
{
    // ...
}
```